# How to use a calculated data item in a chart in cognos?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi

Currently I'm working in Cognos 10.1 and I'm facing this problem. 
I've a **data item (date)** and using that I've calculated the **day** of the **date** (i.e sunday, monday...etc). 
I want to use it in the chart X-axis, to find the total sales on each day. 
Since it is a calculated data item, it is not displaying the day values in the X-axis.
Instead, it is blank. How to sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

If you return the data in a simple list, does it aggregate properly? Is there an aggregate type defined on the calculation (I would think there shouldn't be)?

With calculations and aggregations sometimes I find it easier to break the final result into its own query which references the original query. This way you can separate the steps, as whats likely happening is an odd behavior in the SQL generation due to the nuances of your calculation.